# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars """

Tags: python

This time i am incurring a problem while executing the following code:

```
distance = [np.nan]
speed = [np.nan]
for i in range(1,len(data)):
    distance_dt = distance_cal(data.loc[i-1,'latitude'],data.loc[i-1,'longitude'],data.loc[i,'latitude'],data.loc[i,'longitude'])
speed_dt = distance_dt/(data.loc[i,'delta_time']/3600)
distance.append(distance_dt)
speed.append(speed_dt)
data['distance'] = np.around(distance, decimals=6)
data['speed'] = np.around(speed, decimals=6)
```

Generated Error is:

```
C:\...site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  """
C:\...site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  """
```

I have checked

> \ipykernel_launcher.py 'It's code is given below'.

```
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing import until
after removing the cwd from sys.path.
"""

import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
    # This is added back by InteractiveShellApp.init_path()
    if sys.path[0] == '':
        del sys.path[0]

    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
    app.launch_new_instance()
```

Moreover, distance and speed are two variables/datsets present in excel and contain value either 0,1 or floating number.

Comment: You call it an error, but it says it's a warning. Is it actually crashing your program?

Comment: Hello nick, it is just warning and once it warns, it stops executing the program but it is not crashing the program.

Answer (score 0):

The warning says:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
```

Which basically means, you are trying to divide something by `0`.

```
speed_dt = distance_dt/(data.loc[i,'delta_time']/3600)
```

This statement might be causing this issue.
Try and convert `0` into a anything more or less than `0` and then run again.

Comment: Hello Mayank Porwal, thank you for answer. I cannot change the value 0 to other than 0. As values are critical. Can't we change a code little bit?

Comment: Aha Sorry, I got it wrong. True, we cannot divide 0 by 0. As any thing divide by 0 is infinity. I will try to change 0 to NaN and reply to your solution. Thank you.

Comment: Python automatically rounds off the numbers after division. To stop that, you can put `from __future__ import division` to the top of your script. This will give you the exact divisions. But, if the actual value is `0`, that can't be helped.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I guess, may be we have to modify some code. Exactly where and what that is a little problem for me.

Comment: If the problem is you're dividing by 0 because your delta time is too small to be measured by the data capturing device, why not adding the error of the device to the actual measurement when it's 0? Then you'd have a non-zero division